# Safari rubber-band scrolling on DIVs but not page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I'n my web app I'd like to achieve something like OS X's Mail.app, Reminders.app, Contacts.app etc in which their individual panes have the rubber-band scroll effect, but the overall app does not.

eg in Mail.app, the mailbox list on the left-hand side *does* have the rubber-band effect, but the app of course does not.

In the case of a web-app, this would mean the BODY does not have elastic scrolling but a DIV or two inside the BODY do.

I've managed to remove the rubber-band effect from the body using overflow: hidden; but am not sure if it's possible to re-introduce the effect on specific DIVs.

Comment: The rubber-band scrolling is only active when using a touchpad in OSX. Do you want the same behaviour for your page?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think OS X is most often used with trackpads — even Apple's mouse has a touch sensitive surface.

Answer (score -1):

Have you taken a look at iosslider-vertical? It's a premium plugin but it will do exactly what you are asking. HTML/CSS is fully customizable. Works on both touch and desktop browsers (click+drag & touch+drag supported).

http://iosscripts.com/iosslider-vertical

Comment: Looks like you're right sadly — there's no native way to achieve this. However the link you provided only seems to work on iOS. It doesn't provide the behaviour I am after for OS X.